# How can I access a Swift extension in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-category

I am using the framework [GlyuckDataGrid](https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid) to implement a datagrid in Objective-C. There's an extension called `IndexPath+DataGrid.swift` that is vital to the datagrid's implementation, however it is written in Swift.

I am using CocoaPods and I have the following imports and still unable to access it.

```
@import GlyuckDataGrid;
#import <GlyuckDataGrid/GlyuckDataGrid-Swift.h>
```

E: now that i have the answer to my solution, i want to point out that i overlooked `IndexPath` and `NSIndexPath`. dont be me and confuse the 2...

Comment: your extension should be marked as public, and the extension cannot be defined on a bridged type - have you checked on that?

Comment: @Whakkee ill fork and check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework was using a pure Swift type (`IndexPath`) instead of its Objective-C equivalent (`NSIndexPath`).  In your case, the solution was to extend `NSIndexPath` as well as `IndexPath` to expose the functionality to Objective-C:

> ```
> public extension NSIndexPath {
>     /**
>      Returns an index-path object initialized with the indexes of a specific row and column in a data grid view.
>      - parameter column: An index number identifying a column in a DataGridView object in a row identified by the row parameter.
>      - parameter row:    An index number identifying a row in a DataGridView object.
>      - returns: An NSIndexPath object.
>      */
>     convenience init(forColumn column: Int, row: Int) {
>         self.init(item: column, section: row)
>     }
>
>     /// An index number identifying a column in a row of a data grid view. (read-only)
>     var dataGridColumn: Int {
>         return self.index(atPosition: 1)
>     }
>
>     /// An index number identifying a row in a data grid view. (read-only)
>     var dataGridRow: Int {
>         return self.index(atPosition: 0)
>     }
>
>     /// An index number for single-item indexPath
>     var index: Int {
>         return self.index(atPosition: 0)
>     }
> }
> ```

From [`c281729`](https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid/commit/c2817294988c8c53c63dcc35e1736aa5929227f6).

Comment: thanks, one of the higher ups deleted it before i could.